# Mail Settings for SendGrid using AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email, appharbor, sendgrid

I'm trying to set up email sending for my ASP.NET MVC4 project using SendGrid and AppHarbor. I know AppHarbor injects the relevant SMTP configuration in my application's configuration, but I want to send email locally for testing. I therefore need to know the correct mailSettings to manually add these settings to my application.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" password="XXXX" userName="XXX@apphb.com"></network>
```

I keep getting the error "Failure Sending Email". I copied the username from my SendGrid account, but I'm not sure what to use for the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the password here: https://appharbor.com/applications/name_of_your_app/configurationvariables

Here is where you can find it on the menu: http://www.screencast.com/t/iEaLay3d8